# Consistency strength of an attempt at higher order set theory

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, axioms

Work in a theory with (deep breath) a countable number of primitives denoted with capital letters from the end of the alphabet with numerical subscripts $\{X_n,Y_n,Z_n,\dots\}_{n<\omega}$ indicating which kind of primitive they are together with primitive relations $\{\in_n\}_{n<\omega}$ with numerical subscripts indicating which kind of primitive they are a relation on, such that each $n$-primitive is also an $n+1$-primitive for all $n<\omega$ and such that $\in_n$ is $\in_{n+1}$ restricted to $n$-primitives for all $n<\omega$, and such that each $\in_n$ is *left closed* so primitives to the left of $\in_n$ are at most $n$-primitives. Call $0$-primitives *sets*, and suppress subscripts when they are obvious from context.

For axioms assume $Z$ plus foundation (denoted $Z^+$) for each level of primitives, so we can pair/union/powerset/separate/etc. at each primitive stage. Note that we can pair etc. $n$- and $m$-primitives for $n<m$ since all $n$-primitives are also $m$-primitives. For all $n<\omega$, say that a predicate $\phi$ in the language of this theory is *safe above $n$* iff no $m$-primitives for $m>n$ occur in $\phi$, and let $\Phi_n$ denote the set of all predicates safe above $n$. Add

> **Class Building Axioms**. For all $n$, if $\phi$ is a predicate in the language of this theory safe above $n$, then there exists an $n+1$-primitive $X_{n+1}$ whose members are precisely the $n$-primitives $Y_n$ sayisfying $\phi$. $$\forall\phi\in\Phi_n\exists X_{n+1}\big(Y_n\in X_{n+1}\iff\phi(Y_n)\big).$$ We denote the $n+1$-primitive guaranteed by this axiom together with a predicate $\phi$ safe above $n$ by $$\{Y_n:\phi(Y_n)\}_{n+1}.$$

Define functions as subsets of arbitrary Cartesian products as usual. For all $n<\omega$, define the *$n+1$-primitive of all $n$-primitives* by $$\widehat{V_{n+1}}=\{X_n:X_n=X_n\}_{n+1}.$$

> **Replacement**. If $F$ is a function and $dmnF$ is an $n$-primitive and $F(X)$ is an $n$-primitive for all $X\in dmnF$, then $rngF$ is an $n$-primitive. $$\forall n\forall F(F\ \text{is a function}\wedge dmnF\in \widehat{V_{n+1}}\wedge\forall X\in dmnF(F(X)\in\widehat{V_{n+1}})\implies rngF\in\widehat{V_{n+1}}).$$

This gives us replacement at each stage, since (for example) we can form the $1$-primitive $$X=\{\mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset):n\in\omega\}$$ by class building and form the surjective  function $$\langle\mathcal{P}^n(\emptyset):n<\omega\rangle\subset\omega\times X$$ to prove that $X$ is in fact a set by replacement, then take $\mathcal{P}^\omega(\emptyset)=\bigcup X$ and proceed to define $\mathcal{P}^{\omega+\omega}(\emptyset)$ and higher stages of the cumulative hierarchy as usual.

> **Question**. What is the consistency strength of this theory?

It's bounded above trivially by $ZFC$ plus the existence of a countable number of inaccessible cardinals $\{\kappa_i\}_{i<\omega}$ with $\kappa_i<\kappa_{i+1}$ for all $i<\omega$, where we take $\widehat{V_{n+1}}=V_{\kappa_n}$ for all $n<\omega$ together with usual membership. Is this also a lower bound?

---

**Edit**: Replacement as originally phrased made the theory inconsistent, since for all $n$ we have that $\{(0,\widehat{V_n})\}$ is trivially a function whose domain is a set, so $\{\widehat{V_n}\}$  would be a set for all $n$ and this together with unions yields obvious inconsistencies. I believe the fix proposed above avoids this issue and still allows for use of the axiom in all desired situations, since it correctly describes the kind of replacement we have in the inaccessible cardinal situation.

Comment: At some point you gotta ask yourself, are you doing set theory or are you doing type theory with a "base layer of ZFC".

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm doing what feels most natural to me ;^).

Comment: @AsafKaragila More seriously, the 'apparent typing' of the theory is really much less pronounced in the way I'd like to use it; $1$-primitives should only (provably) crop up as collections of sets 'too logically large to be sets', $2$-primitives should only crop up as collections of $1$-primitives 'too logically large to be $1$-primitives', so on and so forth. We can add large cardinals and stuff to the base theory and retain the ability to 'collect stuff up' indefinitely in a way that, to me, feels very 'naturally set theoretical'. (But I agree, I couldn't find any non-typed presentation.)

Comment: Could you indicate similarities to and differences from NF?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Unfortunately I’ve never worked with NF, could you link in a reference for me to peek at? After a quick wikipedia, it looks like the difference is the weird restriction on the NF comprehension schemata (the equivalent of the class building axioms here, which in contrast allow for arbitrary predicates at each stage).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I also don’t see an equivalent of replacement in NF, which greatly strengthens each ‘primitive stage’ in this theory.

Comment: Concerning literature - I believe the Randall Holmes [New Foundations](https://randall-holmes.github.io/nf.html) page must be optimal (maybe together with some links there). As for replacement, (an $F$ is missing at $F(X)$ there?) could you also clarify - it seems that going over each limit ordinal could increase primitive level by one, so why don't we eventually run out of levels?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე You are correct about the missing $F$, thank you -- as regards replacement, all limit ordinals that provably exist in ZFC are sets in this theory. We have that $\omega$ is a set by the axioms of Zermelo set theory, and we can then construct $\omega+n$ for all $n$ via successors and they're all sets, then form the $1$-predicate $X={^1}\{\omega+n:n<\omega\}$ and observe that $\langle \omega+n:n<\omega\rangle$ is a surjective function with domain $\omega$ such that the image of each natural number is a set, so $X$ is in fact a set and we can define $\omega+\omega=\bigcup X$, etc.

Comment: I see, thanks! But then what kind of operation does force level increase?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The idea is that it should only be forced by those predicates whose 'extensions to a collection' yields a 'collection' so large that it can't 'be a collection of the same kind as its members' on pain of paradox, so for predicates like $X=X$ or $X\notin X$ that usually give contradictions (the former with foundation, the latter in general).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Interestingly, if we drop the axiom of infinity at each stage then limit ordinals *do* force primitive stage increases, so this theory minus infinity is in turn modeled by $V_{\omega^2}$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Actually, I think even if we drop infinity at all stages $\omega$ still crops up as a $1$-primitive by class building and then exists to construct higher limit ordinals at the $1$-primitive stage, so dropping infinity yields a ‘base universe’ $\widehat{V_1}$ of hereditarily finite sets with $Ord_0=\omega\in\widehat{V_2}$, and then $\widehat{V_2}$ has infinity and thusly models all of ZFC (and all higher primitive stages do once again).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე After thinking about this some more, if we remove infinity *and replacement* then the theory is modeled by $V_{\omega^2}$ as a consequence of primitive jumps at each limit ordinal -- if we just add infinity back in the consistency strength doesn't change though, the base layer is just no longer equiconsistent with PA. So this theory and this theory without infinity are equiconsistent, but removing replacement causes a huge drop in consistency strength due to primitive jumps at each limit ordinal since we can no longer 'replace' their higher primitive versions with lower ones.

Comment: Sorry, it is hard for me to follow, but what still worries me is your very last paragraph. Why cannot some similar but much better hidden booby-trap exist in your present version of Replacement?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე An easy way I convinced myself was by proving that the standard axiom of replacement (as it is phrased in ZFC, referring to binary predicates) holds relativized to $\widehat{V_1}$ in this theory, so this (together with $\widehat{V_1}$ modeling $Z^+$ by assumption) gives us that $\widehat{V_1}$ models all of ZFC. Since the membership relation in all the $\widehat{V_n}$'s (in particular in $\widehat{V_1}$) is standard membership, this gives that all standard $ZFC$-ordinals provably exist in $\widehat{V_1}$.

Comment: The answer is No! Because simple ZFC so extended can easily prove the union of the stages indexed after those inaccessible cardinals $\kappa_i$ where $i < \omega$. And that union would serve to model this theory, and it has a countable cofinality, and so doesn't satisfy ZFC. So the lower bound is $\sf Z + \forall \operatorname {ordinal} \alpha (V_\alpha \text{ exists}) $+ there is countably man strongly inaccessible cardinals.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar I ultimately think you’re correct about the theory needing replacement ‘in the background’ in addition to having it inside each collection of collections; I’ll release an edited version of the note in the next few weeks with replacement for all collections added, and an attribution to you for credit in pointing out it’s necessity. Thank you for pointing out a flaw in the theory.

Comment: @AlecRhea. Your welcome! (don't forget to edit your self accepted answer)

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar Or maybe I’ll do neither ;^)

Comment: @AlecRhea, just curious, why do you want your theory to extend ZFC. I mean if it remains as it is, an extension of Z but capturing ZFC inside the n-collections, why that is not satisfying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $ZFC$ plus the existence of a countable collection of strictly inaccessible cardinals is also a lower bound on the consistency strength of this theory, and am posting this as a CW answer to close the question.

For a proof sketch, define ordinals to be hereditarily membership transitive primitives, define rank $\rho$ as usual for all primitives, and for each $n<\omega$ define $$Ord_n=\{X:X\ \text{is an ordinal}\}_{n+1}.$$ In particular, each $Ord_n$ is a proper $n+1$ primitive (it is not also an $n$-primitive) since it is also an ordinal and would thusly be a member of itself by definition if it were an $n$-primitive, contradicting foundation. Further, defining stages of the cumulative hierarchy $V_\alpha$ for ordinals $\alpha$ using rank in the usual way we have that $$V_{Ord_n+1}\models MK$$ for all $n<\omega$. To see this, observe that for all $n<\omega$ we have that  $$V_{Ord_n}=\widehat{V_{n+1}}\models ZFC$$ and if we have two $n+1$-primitives $X,Y\in V_{Ord_n+1}$ (viewed as 'classes over $V_{Ord_n}$') with $X\in Y$ then $$\rho(X)<\rho(Y)\leq Ord_n\implies X\in V_{Ord_n}=\widehat{V_{n+1}},$$ so a 'class $X$ over $V_{Ord_n}$' becomes a 'set in $V_{Ord_n}$' as soon as it is a member of another 'class over $V_{Ord_n}$'. Using the [characterization](https://neugierde.github.io/cantors-attic/Inaccessible) of strictly inaccessible cardinals as those ordinals $\alpha$ such that $V_{\alpha+1}\models MK$, we see that $Ord_n$ is strictly inaccessible for all $n<\omega$.

Comment: In your definition of your theory, $n$ for $n$-primitives lives in the metatheory (or in other words, they are standard natural numbers.) Thus I doubt whether we can formulate $\hat{V}_n$ uniform to $n$ within your theory.

Comment: What you can do the best seems to me that you can interpret for each (standard) natural $n$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "there are $n$ inaccessible cardinals" is interpretable within your theory. This is significantly different from interpreting $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "there are $\omega$ inaccessibles" within your theory.

Comment: @HanulJeon I’m not sure I understand your point about the naturals in the metatheory — I ended up writing a short [note](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10060) on this theory and uploading it to the arxiv; does this help clarify things, or can you specify more precisely where your doubts lie?

Comment: In your draft, how did you define predicates safe above $n$? It seems to me that you defined predicates over the metatheory (as a formula of the language.) When you define the axiom A4, you quantified over formulas that are not formalizable over a theory (by Tarski's undefinability.)

Comment: The above point can be circumvented by formulating A4 as an axiom schema, stating as an axiom for each formula that is safe above $n$. However, the such formulation does not allow formulating the axiom for arbitrary natural numbers within a theory. For example, consider a model of $\mathsf{ZFC+\lnot Con(ZFC)}$. This model satisfies Separation and Replacement for all $\Sigma_n$ formulas for standard $n$ (that is, natural numbers $n$ that corresponds the actual natural numbers over the metalanguage,) but there is a nonstandard natural number $m$ in the model such that (cont'd)

Comment: $\Sigma_m$-Separation or Replacement fails over any structures in this model.

Comment: I am not sure my previous comment points out the issue clearly, but overall, your formulation conflates the distinction between object languages and metalanguages which are very subtle to distinguish. Learning the Reflection theorem in set theory would be helpful to distinguish these two if you have not learned it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Replacement is not one of your background axioms, and your theory doesn't prove it. Extend $\sf ZFC$ with countably infinite many inaccessibles $icc_0, icc_1,icc_2,...$ ; now let $\kappa= \bigcup \{icc_n \mid n \in \omega\}$, then $(V_\kappa,\in^{V_\kappa})$ is a model of your main theory, and $(V_{\kappa+\omega}, \in^{V_{\kappa+\omega}})$ is a model of your theory with the completion axiom A6. And clearly none of these models satisfy replacement. The lower bound on your main theory is $\sf Z +$$ \forall n \in \omega: icc_n \text{ exists }$, and on your theory with A6 schema is $\sf Z$$+ V_\kappa \text{ exists }$, where $\kappa$ defined above.